# Why won't the compiler treat the Circle class as an instance?

Tags: java

Right now I am trying to instantiate the Circle class (which is a subclass of Shape) in a method in my menu class. But the problem is that I keep getting a compiler error say Circle cannot be resolved to a type. In other words in does not even recognize my Circle class as an instance, it just thinks it's another variable. I've tried using variables in the instantiation and I have tried using setters in the constructor.

Here is the method in the menu class where I am trying to instantiate Circle

```
public void select_case()
    {
        switch (menu_select)
        {
            case 1: Circle c = new Circle(1);
                    break;



        }

    }
```

Just in case you need to know, menu_select is a private integer variable.

Here is the code for my Circle class. I am only going to show the constructors to make less clutter.

```
public class Circle extends Shape 
{
    final private pi = Java.lang.Math.PI;
    //Constructor
     Circle(double r)
     {
        super(r);
     }
}
```

And here is the code for the shape superclass. Like the code for the circle class only the constructors are shown.

```
public abstract class Shape 
{
    private static double scaleFactor;
    private double base;
    private double radius;
    private double height;
    //Constructor for circle
    public Shape(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }   
    //Constructor for rectangle
    public Shape(double b, double h)
    {
        base = b;
        height = h;
    }


}
```

Comment: Are they both in the same package (your main and your Circle type)?  Also, might want to change the constructor for Circle to be public.

Comment: `final private pi` lacks a `double`.

Comment: Copy-paste the error you're getting.

Comment: Have not used pi yet, and the shape class won't instantiate either and it has a public marker.

Comment: Can't copy and paste error message. It is one of those pop up bubbles.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. You can format it like you do your code so that it's on its own line. Also can you describe the file and folder structure for your Java classes?

Comment: What IDE are you suing? You should be able to compile the code so that the error message appears in the output window rather than just using the tooltip error messages in the IDE.

Comment: Your Circle class is probably not compiling because of the errors with PI. Also if the Circle class is not in the same package as the Menu class, you need to declare the Circle constructor as public.

Comment: I made the circle constructor public and I have fixed pi and it still won't work. It's probably the package. How do I access the default package?

Comment: Are they in different packages? If yes, then do you have the proper import statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final private pi = Java.lang.Math.PI;
```

should be

```
private final double pi = java.lang.Math.PI;
```

or just

```
private final double pi = Math.PI;
```

I don't see any errors in the code other than this.

Comment: you are missing the type annotation

Comment: That member variable is irrelevant to the problem since I have not used it yet, but I did fix it anyways and I still have the error.

Comment: Well are you sure you posted all the relevant parts? Because what you have (with the change above) seems to compile fine.

Comment: It's probably the package. How do I access the default package?